# Use of support vector machine algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, svm

I am using Python and trying to load a .csv file and use Support Vector Machine algorithm. I am a beginner and saw a tutorial on youtube, my file contains all the features and the userid at the end.

[These are the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNPHj.png)

[And this is where I am getting an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfsGC.png)

I have imported everything and have used "df = pd.read_csv('Results.csv')" to load the file.
I just want to use SVM to find the accuracy.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code and error in your question.  Do not post links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your're using the return value of the `train_test_split` function incorrectly. It should be `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = ...`, not `X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = ...` (it's clearly stated in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)).